# How to insert an item in "SList" using Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

With the below program, Java does not allow non-final variables to be used in thread to avoid "data race" unlike C++11, which makes sense. Using `synchronized` keyword with `insertFront()` would also not make sure that right value of `j` would get insert in list.

```
public class Dummy2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final SList list = new SList();
        for(Integer j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    list.insertFront(j);
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }

        // not sure, how to join the threads with above code.
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            Object obj = list.nth(i);
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

    }
}
```

can make this work by `final Integer k = j;` with inconsistent values

Here is the insertFront() operation in `class SList`

```
public synchronized void insertFront(Object obj) {
    head = new SListNode(obj, head);
    size++;
  }
```

---

Here is nth() method

```
 public Object nth(int position) {
    SListNode currentNode;
    if ((position < 1) || (head == null)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      currentNode = head;
      while (position > 1) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        if (currentNode == null) {
          return null;
        }
        position--;
      }
      return currentNode.item;
    }
  }
```

---

```
  SList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
  }
```

As of now, Please do not encourage me to use existing Java packages.

Please let me know, how can insert operation happen in `SList` using thread with consistent values in the above program?

*Note: New to multithreading*

Comment: Wait, what's the problem?

Comment: _It is obvious that `insertFront()` operation does not work, because `SList` is declared as `final`_ Expand on this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry for the confusion, penalize me for this. please see the query edit.

Comment: You're trying to do concurrent programming, but you aren't protecting your critical sections.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is that not correct to say, `insertFront()` is the critical section? which am protecting using `synchronized`  keyword.

Comment: Sure, but `nth` isn't. Also you're trying to insert element asynchronously. Nothing guarantees that any elements will be added before you try to retrieve them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i think i need to join those threads in `main()` before i try retrieve them, How do i join threads here?

Comment: Store the `Thread` instances. Call `join` on them.

Comment: Before joining, I would like to understand, Does `Thread th` point to valid reference after thread starts(`th.start()`) and completes her execution?

Comment: Of course it does, why do you think it wouldn't? Also, you need to make the distinction between a thread and a `Thread` object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so every `Thread` object can launch one thread for one time. after launching the thread, thread can go to different states. So, it is not safe to terminate `Thread` object until thread gets terminated, am i correct?

Comment: Who said anything about terminating? I really suggest reading the official tutorials on threads.

Answer (score 1):

> Java does not allow non-final variables to be used in thread to avoid
>   "data race"

This is false.  It's telling you to use a final variable because you're referencing it from within an anonymous inner class (your Runnable).

Further, final or not, your SList is never instantiated, thus your problems.  Try changing

```
final SList list = null;
```

to

```
final SList list = new SList();
```

And what's an `SList` anyway?

Comment: And, you're not showing what `head` is defined as, or where (or if) it's been instantiated.